# Replace Corroded Copper Pipe With PEX?

Tags: plumbing, shower, pex, corrosion, copper-pipe

I hired a contractor to renovate my shower. He has a five star rating with 40 reviews on Google Maps and four years on the Better Business Bureau with no complaints.

Yesterday I turned off the water, ran the downstairs sinks, and he replaced some of the copper with PEX and the old shower valve with a new [Delta R10000-UNBXHF](https://www.homedepot.com/p/204082131) and cartridge from the [Delta Tetra 1-Handle Wall-Mount Shower Trim Kit](https://www.homedepot.com/p/324873147).

He's taking the weekend off and will be back on Monday to install the cement boards and RedGard waterproofing. I've checked the plumbing several times yesterday and today and don't see or feel any leaks so far.

The plumbing was installed when the house was built in 1986. The remaining copper pipe has some corrosion on it and I'm worried about eventual pinhole leaks. Should I offer to pay him extra to remove most of this remaining copper and replace it with PEX? Anything else about this plumbing that I should ask him to change before he puts the cement boards up?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Copper does not corrode. It builds a protective layer of oxide and will live like the for years to come.

Comment: Most copper pipe should be good for at least 60 to 80 years.  There is/was some chinese made pipe, but that is from the early 2000s, so your pipe should be just middle age.

Comment: My speculation is that your corrosion was caused by residual flux from when the copper was soldered. I would take one of those green Scotch Brite pads and polish the pipe a bit. Once the green is gone, then you can detect how bad the corrosion was based on your sense of touch. If that's an interior wall on the other side of the cavity, so you can easily cut in to fix a pinhole leak, then the corrosion would need to be _really_ bad before I would replace more copper. But soldering in a new piece is no bid deal for me.

Answer (score 1):

The plumbing looks good.  There is some corrosion on the surface that can be cleaned off with a light abrasive pad, if it really bothers you.

My condo had issues with pinholes in copper pipes.  In every instance the leaks were at places where concrete was sloppily dropped on the pipes and allowed to remain.  In your instance the pipes look ok.

Comment: Great - this is really helpful. Thank you!